# How does Rails 4 live work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am asking for a explanation that includes some or all of the below. A chronological descriptions would be very helpful starting with the initial request made by the client.

1. What client-side technologies (parts of HTML 5 if any) are being used (websockets?)
2. What are the requirements on the server-side to make use of this technology? (ie. multi-treading, multi-process, etc)
3. What protocols are being enabled? (HTTP persistance-keep-alive, low-level sockets, TCP or just HTTP?)

Comment: IF your'e referring to the Live Streaming feature in Rails 4, see http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html.